# 2 Shaders using the same vertex data

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, glsl

So im having problems rendering using 2 different shaders. Im currently rendering shapes that represent dice, what i want is if the dice is selected by the user, it draws an outline by drawing the dice completely red and slightly scaled up, then render the proper dice over it. At the moment some of the dice, for some reason, render the wrong dice for the outline, but the right one for the proper foreground dice.

Im wondering if they aren't getting their vertex data mixed up somehow. Im not sure if doing something like this is even allowed in openGL:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVertices*sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(effect->vertCoord);        
glVertexAttribPointer(effect->vertCoord, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(effect->toon_vertCoord);        
glVertexAttribPointer(effect->toon_vertCoord, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

im trying to bind the vertex data to 2 different shaders here
when i load my first shader i have:

```
vertCoord = glGetAttribLocation(TexAndLighting, "position");
```

and the other shader has:

```
toon_vertCoord = glGetAttribLocation(Toon, "position");
```

if I use the shaders independently of each other they work fine, but when i try to render both one on top of the other they get the model mixed up some times. here is how my draw function looks:

```
- (void) draw {
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray); 

effect->modelViewMatrix = mvm;
effect->numberColour = GLKVector4Make(numbers[colorSelected].r, numbers[colorSelected].g, numbers[colorSelected].b, 1);
effect->faceColour = GLKVector4Make(faceColors[colorSelected].r, faceColors[colorSelected].g, faceColors[colorSelected].b, 1);

if(selected){
    [effect drawOutline]; //this function prepares the shader
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}

[effect prepareToDraw]; //same with this one
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

this is what it looks like, as you can see most of the outlines are using the wrong dice, or none at all:
[image: picture of dice]

links to full code:
http://pastebin.com/yDKb3wrD Dice.mm //rendering stuff
http://pastebin.com/eBK0pzrK Effects.mm //shader stuff
http://pastebin.com/5LtDAk8J //my shaders, shouldn't be anything to do with them though

TL;DR: trying to use 2 different shaders that use the same vertex data, but its getting the models mixed up when rendering using both at the same time, well thats what i think is going wrong, quite stumped actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, in that this is not allowed (or rather it doesn't do what you think):

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(effect->vertCoord);        
glVertexAttribPointer(effect->vertCoord, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(effect->toon_vertCoord);        
glVertexAttribPointer(effect->toon_vertCoord, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

Attributes have no particular linkage to shaders. You can't tell OpenGL "attribute *N* is for this shader, and attribute *M* is for this other shader."

Attributes simply bind to indexes, and any shader that happens to have an input at that index will slurp the data that was last bound to that particular index.

So if you have two shaders, lets call them "toon" and "normal", which have the following inputs (this is hypothetical):

```
normal
  input vertCoord (index = 0)
  input texCoord (index = 1)

toon
  input toon_vertCoord (index = 0)
  input toon_somethingElse (index = 1)
```

Then when you run this code:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(effect->vertCoord);        
glVertexAttribPointer(effect->vertCoord, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(effect->toon_vertCoord);        
glVertexAttribPointer(effect->toon_vertCoord, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

draw_normal_object();
```

Your `effect->vertCoord` is no longer bound to anything, because `toon_vertCoord` has the same index, and you've overwritten the input pointer. So here your normal shader will be sampling from the `toon_vertCoord`, and everything will be all messed up.

What you want to do is to enable/pointer all of the attributes for "normal shader", draw the normal objects, then switch to the toon shader, enable/pointer all of the toon attributes, and then draw the toon objects.

Comment: Don't forget that you can use `glBindAttribLocation` before linking to assign the attribute index for a particular vertex attribute on a shader.

Comment: Ah thanks guys (again, since you two answered my last question), ill try this out as soon as I can. As you can see im still learning OpenGL :P

Comment: is this what you had in mind with your answer? http://pastebin.com/KbjYym6q
it seems to work for the most part, except im getting a strange problem where its like the first shader (toon/outline shader) doesnt use its vert shader, and only the fragment shader, cause it gets the colour right, just doesnt scale up the model like its meant to (can check out my shaders in the link in my question). i have to disable drawing the one way to be able to see the other, they wont work at the same time which is really odd.

Comment: @Fonix You set the modelviewmatrix for both shaders?

Comment: yeah i do by going `effect->modelViewMatrix = mvm;` in the draws sets the modelViewMatrix. im not sure it has anything to do with that really since it does seem to draw fine if i draw using the one shader and not the other. But maybe something is tricking me that im overlooking about it...

Comment: in my shader i have
`vec4 scaled = position * 1.55;  
      
gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * scaled;`
changing that 1.55 seems to have no effect, which is really odd because before i made the changes you suggested, it did have an effect

Comment: Ok my bad, it seems going `position * 1.55` isn't what I thought it would be doing. I changed it to `vec4 scaled = position * vec4(1.15,1.15,1.15,1);` and now its working perfectly. Thanks again for the help. (Odd that it was scaling the model before, and now that I changed my code to what you suggested, now it needs to be multiplied by an actual vector. I guess the W component is quite important or something) edit: actually now that i think about it, it would mess up the MVP matrix quite badly.. woops